# How to extract specyfic file from zip file - windows 10?

Tags: zip, extract, rar

is there possible to extract only specific files from zip file using Windows 10 and some application or script?
Could you recommend something, please? I have trying find some info in Internet, but I can't find nothing which is useful for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. On the command prompt;

```
tar xf <YourArchive.zip> <FileToBeExtracted>
```

All Windows PC has this command to begin with. No installation required.

If you prefer GUI, you can extract in the file explorer. Open inside of a zip file, select a file to be extracted, and then drag & drop it to somewhere at outside of the zip file. Copy & paste will work as well.

Comment: The sentence below the command line example is a lie. All Windows prior Windows 10 do not have `tar.exe` installed by default at all. For Windows 10 the version of Windows 10 depends on `tar.exe` being available by default or not as documented by the Microsoft developers on blog page [Tar and Curl Come to Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows). `tar.exe` is available by default on Windows 11. However, questions being off-topic for Stack Overflow should not be answered at all.